How to modify the behaviour of output in Xcode's playground?
I just started to learn Swift, and I am watching the "Swift Programming Tutorial - Full Course for Beginners" on YouTube, I noticed that the playground setting in the tutorial is a bit different from mine Tutorial set up
as you can see in the image, the Xcode displays the content of the array on the right side, but what I have is this: my xcode
It is not very convenient, as I need to manually click to expand the result and click again to minimize them; and the way that my Xcode displays its output is very inefficient in another way, for most of the time it doesn't display anything meaningful like the content of the result, but rather tends to display what data type is the result.
Other Examples
My macOS was Sonoma 14.0 and Xcode is Version 15.4 (15F31d), it was an IOS playground.
I tried to go to behavior in the setting and changed it to the Variable View : My setting
And it doesn't work even though I have restarted it several times, it would still display the same thing as the screenshots I provided.
Can someone help me with this, please? Thank you.
